# angular.js - simplest way to handle click inside controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

is there any better way of handling clicks inside a controller than this?

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController>
  <a href="/#!/something" ng-click="doTheSame()">link1</a>
  <a href="/#!/something" ng-click="doTheSame()">link2</a>
  <a href="/#!/something" ng-click="doTheSame()">link3</a>
  ..
  <a href="/#!/something" ng-click="doTheSame()">link99</a>
</div>
```

in jQuery I would do something like:

```
$('div > a').on('click', function() {
  // do some stuff
});
```

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? A generic way to add doTheSame() to every link inside a page or div?

Comment: yes, I updated my question with jQuery example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really want to handle any DOM stuff in controllers (a controller just ties *data* to the view, which happens to be the DOM).

You want to use a **directive** for DOM manipulation. (However, yes, `ng-click` is a built-in directive that can run methods inside the controller).

If you'd like to attach some behavior to an element, you can do something like this:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', myDirective);

myDirective.$inject = ['whateverService'];

function myDirective(whateverService) {
    var d = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };

    return d;

    function link(scope, $el, attrs) {
        $el.on('click', doSomething);

        function doSomething() { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div myDirective></div>
```

See [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) for more info.

You can have multiple of these directives, and you can even pass in data:

```
<div myDirective="first-link">First</div>
<div myDirective="second-link">Second</div>
<!-- etc. -->
```